# AngularJS ng-repeat directive, created dynamically does not work

Tags: angularjs

i tried to add a ng-repeat directive in a compile method of other directive but it is not work.

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yiooxir/mdptnqo5/1/

I expected that the 'field' directive be fruitful in the three fields (input) but this is not happening

here is my code:

**html:**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
   {{object.var}}
   <field value='object.var' plural></field>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.object = {
      var: [1, 2, 3]
   }
 });

app.directive('field', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        value: '='
    },
    template: "<div><input type='text' ng-model='value'></div>",
    link: function() {}
  }
})

app.directive('plural', function($compile){
  return {
    priority: 1001,
    compile: function(element, attr) {
        element.attr({
            'ng-repeat': 'i in object.var track by $index',
            'value': 'object.var[$index]',
            'button': ''
        });
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in plural directive at the end of compile function

```
    return function(scope, element) { 
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
```

Comment: yes. this can also be done if we add the following code as shown below:

<pre>

  compile: function(element, attr) {
  element.attr({
            'ng-repeat': 'i in object.var track by $index',
            'value': 'object.var[$index]',
        });
  var parent = element.parent();
  parent.append(element)

</pre>

but it is unclear why so ? most of other directives don't recuire it